# Trying to set alpha with data binding from another view's visibility

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have an example running like this:

```
<Switch
            android:id="@+id/sw_state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:enabled="@{!swAuto.checked}"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Zustand"
            android:textColor="@{swAuto.checked ? @color/outlet_preview_card_text_disabled : @color/outlet_preview_card_text}"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:textColor="@color/outlet_preview_card_text"/>
```

But I need to set the alpha in another view depending on another's view visibility like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_global_outlet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_background_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:alpha="@{ivProgressBar.visibility == View.VISIBLE ? 0.90 : 1}"
        android:padding="10dp">
```

But I am getting this error:

Error:(45, 30) Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'visibility' on type 'android.widget.ImageView'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

this is the view I should depend on:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_animation"/>
```

Comment: Have you imported `View` class?

Comment: yes I have imported the class like         <import type="android.view.View"/>

Comment: Why have you added these two different visibility attributes: `android:visibility="gone"` and `tools:visibility="visible"`?

Comment: the tools one will only be effective before compiling

Answer (score 20):

In case someone wonders I couldn't do it that way.

I decided that when my VM calls startProgressBar() this method will update my model having a field called isUpdating which will be Bindable and my VM extends Observable so with this:

```
android:alpha="@{shDevice.isUpdating ? 0.3f : 1.0f}"
```

would do what I want